# Regexp - find specific string in comma separated string

Tags: regex

#### String to find

`b`

#### Tested strings

1. `b,ffb,x`
2. `b`
3. `<empty-string>`
4. `x,b`
5. `df,b,x`

#### Poor attempt

`[\s|,|^]+(b)[\s|,|$]+`

1. `[\s|,|^]+` - find white space, comma or beginning of string
2. `(b)` - find the desired string
3. `[\s|,|$]+` - find white space, comma or end of string

#### Notes

if `b` defined twice I want to have a match as well

Comment: Why *poor* attempt? :) It is nice but you should understand that `|` inside a character class matches a literal `|` char, same as `$` that is no longer a string end anchor. *Character* classes match *characters*, not locations inside strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe in a character class doesn't denote *alternation* but a literal pipe character. That's true about caret `^` and any other special characters (except a few cases). They will loose their meaning inside a character class.

You need `(^|[\s,])b([\s,]|$)` or simply `\bb\b`.

> if `b` defined twice I want to have a match as well...

I assume you are talking about such cases `b,b,b,x` then you have to change second capturing group to a positive lookahead. This will work if your flavor supports it (Python does):

```
(^|[\s,])b(?=[\s,]|$)
```